# Using JSON with Laravel Mix Postcss Uncss plugin

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-mix

I'm trying to feed json data from a URL to a `postcss-uncss`, as the list of pages that `postcss-uncss` should analyze but I cant seem to get it to see the data. It complains that `pageList` is undefined. How can I do this?

```
const request = require("request")
var url = "http://domain.dev/uncss.json";
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    let pageList = JSON.parse(body);
  }
})
mix.options({
  postCss: [
    require('autoprefixer')(),
    // This is not a laravel project, so we cant use PurifyCSS...
    require('postcss-uncss')({
      html: pageList,
      ignore: [/.(uniform|form-error-hint|error|valid|required)/]
    }),
  ],
})
```